# Django serialize datetime to json in QuerySet/Dict

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, json

I've tried to serialize `QuerySet` or `Dict` object with `datetime.date` object in the following ways:

**Way #1:**

```
json.dumps(MyModel.objects.values())
```

Raises error:

> Exception Value: [{'date': datetime.date(2012, 5, 26), 'time':
>   datetime.time(0, 42, 27)}] is not JSON serializable

**Way #2:**

```
json.dumps(MyModel.objects.values(), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Also raises error:

> Exception Value: [{'date': datetime.date(2012, 5, 26), 'time':
>   datetime.time(0, 42, 27)}] is not JSON serializable

**Way #3:**

```
json.dumps(MyModel.objects.all(), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Exception Value: [< MyModel: MyModel object>] is not JSON serializable

**Way #4:**

```
serializers.serialize('json', MyModel.objects.all())
```

Raises error:

> Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

*How to serialize object with  datetime's field to JSON in Django?*

Comment: `json.dumps(value, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)` is working for me with the `value` copied from the exception you're getting in #2. Could you give any more information, the Python and Django versions could be relevant? (I tested this with Python 2.7.1 and Django 1.3.1)

Comment: @georgebrock sorry, this way is really works. I had another mistake in my code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with datetimes. It's simply that querysets are not by themselves directly serializable, even with the DjangoJSONEncoder class and even using `values()`. You'll get exactly the same result with a model with no datetime fields at all.

The way you're supposed to do serialization in Django is to use `serializers`:

```
from django.core import serializers
output = serializers.serialize('json', MyModel.objects.all())
```

But no doubt you're trying to avoid that because the output format is so unnecessarily complex. Instead, I usually use the 'python' serializer to convert to a dict, then dump to json:

```
temp_output = serializers.serialize('python', MyModel.objects.all())
output = json.dumps(temp_output, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works. But `serializers.serialize` returns result in `{fields: {...}, model: "...", pk: "..."}` form. There is way to return only fields, like this: {field1: "...", field2: "...", ...}?

Comment: Add field as an argument to serializers.serialize() function. `json_serialized_objects = serializers.serialize("json", query_agao, fields=("fieldname1", "fieldname2"))`. More info, see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25564526/3001007](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25564526/3001007)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to just dump a dictionary to JSON, just use json.dumps. It can easily be made to serialize objects by passing in a custom serialization class - there's one included with Django that deals with datetimes already:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
json.dumps(mydict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i have retrieved datetime in json format,

```
from django.core import serializers
_data = serializers.serialize('json', MyModel.objects.all())
bi_data = [i.get('fields', i) for i in json.loads(_data) if i]
```