# <Django Object>: is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django

Here's my view:

```
def display_maps(request):
#query_agao = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=search_term)
#x = Owner.objects.select_related('landproperty_butuanmaps').get(id=5)
query_agao = ButuanMaps.objects.all().select_related('landproperty')[:10]
query_all = ButuanMaps.objects.all()[:10]
djf = Django.Django(geodjango='geom', properties=['id','clandpin','ssectionid'])
geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
butuan_agao = geoj.encode(djf.decode(query_agao.transform(3857)))
return render(request, "index.html", {
    'butuan_agao': butuan_agao,
    'query_agao': query_agao,
    'query_all': query_all})
```

`id` and `clandpin` are not foreignkey, but `ssectionid`.

So, how to serialize foreign keys?

Answer (score 2):

You can use serializers class like this :

```
from django.core import serializers
query_agao = ButuanMaps.objects.all().select_related('landproperty')[:10]
json_serialized_objects = serializers.serialize("json", query_agao)
```

if you only want to serialize few fields do this :

```
json_serialized_objects = serializers.serialize("json", query_agao, fields=("fieldname1", "fieldname2"))
```

where fieldname1 and fieldname2 are attributes of landproperty model class.

Alternately you can do a write a custom serializer for your landproperty class and use it at the time of calling render.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it returned an error, `'str' object has no attribute 'transform'`

Comment: you can check if query_agao is a queryset object(it should not be a single model object),  it will be helpful if you can post the stack trace.